# How Do I Add and Email Attendees An Invite In Django (Google Calendar Integration)

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a booking app with Django that allows people to book a session but I've run into an issue where the API won't allow me to add attendees. The error that I keep getting is:

<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/02g427gf151ggdmcas2pui1suo%40group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json returned "Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.". Details: "[{'domain': 'calendar', 'reason': 'forbiddenForServiceAccounts', 'message': 'Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.'}

I've tried deploying the app and using Google Workspace to delegate authority but that doesn't seem to work. I have a virtual environment and below is the code for the app:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime
from .calendar_API import *
import stripe

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    month_from_now = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)

    if request.method == "POST":
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        desc = request.POST.get("desc")
        date = request.POST.get("daterange")
        email = request.POST.get("email")

        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
        hour_later = date + timedelta(minutes=60)

        hour_later = hour_later.isoformat()

        date = date.isoformat()


        def create_event():

            service = build_service()

            # start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
            event = (
                service.events()
                .insert(
                    calendarId="02g427gf151ggdmcas2pui1suo@group.calendar.google.com",
                    body={
                        "summary": subject,
                        "description": desc,
                        "start": {
                            "dateTime": date,
                            "timeZone":"Europe/London"
                            },
                        "end": {
                            "dateTime": hour_later,
                            "timeZone":"Europe/London"
                        },
                        
                        "attendees": [
                            {
                            "email":email
                            }
                        ],

                        # "sendNotifications": True,
                       
                    },
                )
                .execute()
            )

            print(event)


        create_event()

    context = {'tomorrow' : tomorrow, 'month' : month_from_now}

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**calendar_API.py**

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

import pytz
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from . import views

service_account_email = "booking-app@booking-app-318011.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename="scheduling/credentials.json", scopes=SCOPES
)


def build_service():
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    return service
```

Are there any alternative approaches or documentation regarding this that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

> Service accounts cannot invite attendees without Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority

The issue is that you are using a service account. But you have either forgotten to set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) in your google workspace account or it is not set up properly.

Service accounts only work with google calendar though google workspace it does not work with normal gmail accounts.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/service.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@example.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Performing domain-wide delegation is only the first step needed if you want to use a service account for your task.**

You will also have to impersonate another account in your domain which has access to the specific calendar in order to perform the request.

The main purpose of granting domain-wide authority to a *service account* is for these accounts to be able to access data on behalf of a user in your domain as otherwise the *service account* acts like just another account and it is trying to access its own calendars.

Therefore  when this *service account* impersonates another user in your domain, it will  be able to access the calendars this user can.

In order to perform this, you will  have to  include the email address of the user you want to impersonate when  setting up the credentials in your code.

#### Reference

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#python);
- [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth).